How to implement this type of Multi Dependent Dropdown using ValueNotifiers and FutureProviders from Riverpod 2
I have 3 API calls made using Riverpod Future Provider and family modifier in last two: getAllCategoriesProvider, getSubCategoriesByCategoryIdProvider, getBrandsBySubCategoryIdProvider
My current code slightly works but gives markNeedsBuild error and third dropdown is empty initially, as it's not called because selectedSubCategoryId remains null even after second dropdown is built or refreshed in response of first dropdown changes. When I select from second dropdown then only third refreshes.
Any way to fix this, or any other way to implement this?

All the APIs are working correctly. This is my current code :
class AddProductView extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const AddProductView({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _AddProductViewState();
}

class _AddProductViewState extends ConsumerState<AddProductView> {
  ValueNotifier<String?> selectedCategoryId = ValueNotifier(null);
  ValueNotifier<String?> selectedSubCategoryId = ValueNotifier(null);
  ValueNotifier<String?> selectedBrandId = ValueNotifier(null);

  @override
  void dispose() {
    selectedCategoryId.dispose();
    selectedSubCategoryId.dispose();
    selectedBrandId.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final iconColor = context.cs.onSurface;
    final iconSize = .02.sh;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: IconButton.filledTonal(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded,
                  ),
                )),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: .05.sw, vertical: .05.sh),
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(flex: 4, child: _buildImagePicker()),
                    context.eeswg,
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 3,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          _buildCategoryDropdown(iconColor),
                          context.mhg,
                          _buildSubCategoryDropdown(iconColor),
                          context.mhg,
                          _buildBrandDropdown(iconColor)
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Expanded(flex: 8, child: SizedBox())
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCategoryDropdown(Color iconColor) {
    return ref.watch(categoriesFutureProvider).when(
          data: (data) {
            final category = data.first;
            selectedCategoryId.value = category.cid;

            return DropdownMenu<String>(
              expandedInsets: EdgeInsets.zero,
              leadingIcon: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: .01.sw, right: .008.sw),
                child: HugeIcon(
                    icon: HugeIcons.strokeRoundedDashboardSquare02,
                    color: iconColor),
              ),
              menuHeight: .25.sh,
              initialSelection: category.cid,
              dropdownMenuEntries: data
                  .map(
                    (e) => DropdownMenuEntry<String>(
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        textStyle: WidgetStatePropertyAll(
                            context.tm?.copyWith(fontSize: .008.sw)),
                      ),
                      value: e.cid,
                      label: e.name,
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
              onSelected: (String? id) async {
                selectedCategoryId.value = id;
                selectedSubCategoryId.value = null;
                selectedBrandId.value = null;
              },
            );
          },
          error: (error, stackTrace) => const CustomErrorWidget(),
          loading: () => const CustomLoadingWidget(),
        );
  }

  Widget _buildSubCategoryDropdown(Color iconColor) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: selectedCategoryId,
        builder: (context, cid, _) {
          if (cid == null) {
            return const EmptyDropdownWidget();
          }
          return Consumer(builder: (context, refx, _) {
            return refx.watch(subCategoriesByCategoryIdProvider(cid!)).when(
                  data: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return const EmptyDropdownWidget();
                    }
                    final subCategory = value.first;
                    selectedSubCategoryId.value = subCategory.scid;

                    return DropdownMenu<String>(
                      expandedInsets: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      leadingIcon: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: .01.sw, right: .008.sw),
                        child: HugeIcon(
                            icon: HugeIcons.strokeRoundedDashboardSquare02,
                            color: iconColor),
                      ),
                      menuHeight: .25.sh,
                      initialSelection: subCategory.scid,
                      dropdownMenuEntries: value.map((e) {
                        return DropdownMenuEntry<String>(
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            textStyle: WidgetStatePropertyAll(
                                context.tm?.copyWith(fontSize: .008.sw)),
                          ),
                          value: e.scid,
                          label: e.name,
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onSelected: (String? id) async {
                        selectedSubCategoryId.value = id;
                        selectedBrandId.value = null;
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  error: (error, stackTrace) => const CustomErrorWidget(),
                  loading: () => const CustomLoadingWidget(),
                );
          });
        });
  }

  Widget _buildBrandDropdown(Color iconColor) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: selectedSubCategoryId,
        builder: (context, scid, _) {
          if (scid == null) {
            return const EmptyDropdownWidget();
          }
          return Consumer(builder: (context, refx, _) {
            return refx.watch(brandsBySubCategoryIdProvider(scid!)).when(
                  data: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return const EmptyDropdownWidget();
                    }
                    final brand = value.first;
                    selectedBrandId.value = brand.bid;

                    return DropdownMenu<String>(
                      expandedInsets: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      leadingIcon: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: .01.sw, right: .008.sw),
                        child: HugeIcon(
                            icon: HugeIcons.strokeRoundedDashboardSquare02,
                            color: iconColor),
                      ),
                      menuHeight: .25.sh,
                      initialSelection: brand.bid,
                      dropdownMenuEntries: value
                          .map(
                            (e) => DropdownMenuEntry<String>(
                              style: ButtonStyle(
                                textStyle: WidgetStatePropertyAll(
                                    context.tm?.copyWith(fontSize: .008.sw)),
                              ),
                              value: e.bid,
                              label: e.name,
                            ),
                          )
                          .toList(),
                      onSelected: (String? id) async {
                        selectedBrandId.value = id;
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  error: (error, stackTrace) => const CustomErrorWidget(),
                  loading: () => const CustomLoadingWidget(),
                );
          });
        });
  }
}

